# wordpress integration html & Css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So i need to integrate on Wordpress my own HTML & CSS code, for that I use the theme " Html5blank-stable " which can allow me to start from a " white sheet ", my website is pretty simple because I have only 2 pages to integrate.

I started to like this, in my file WordPress I have an another file for the themes in this one I have the file " Html5blank-stable ", inside I have " template-home.php " who correspond to my home page with my own HTML code, the head tag is in " header.php " that I include with PHP on "template-home.php " and the page is working so good.

The problem comes with the second page, first I create a new page on WordPress that I call " membership " with the URL " http://localhost:8888/template-membership/ " who correspond to the name of my second page in my " Html5blank-stable " file I put my HTML in this one create a CSS file " membership.css " and an " header-membership.php ", but now when I click on my page some pictures does not work..[Error that i have in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIbXY.png)

I hope you will be able to understand me, thank you guy's :)

Comment: replace ../wp-content with /wp-content

Comment: Show us the actual php code related to the generation of the image uri. Either add it to your question or create a gist or codepen then link to it.

Comment: It's ok for me thank you, just the wrong path after 4-5 hours of coding my brain was off ^^

Comment: @LucTst Please mark my answer as accepted. Or, if you feel my answer was not of help, you should post your own answer and then mark it as accepted in 2 days. This way, people can learn from your issue, and see what your solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have uploaded all images well inside your theme images folder.

Now instead of static path try to call all your images using WordPress function `get_template_directory_uri()` like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/girl-bg.jpg" />
```

It will take the dynamic path of your current theme directory and this is the standard way to call images from theme folder.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The console shows that it is looking for a file located at:

```
http://localhost:8888/template-membership/wp-content/themes/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/images/girl-bg.jpg
```

When in fact it should (presumably) be looking for the file:

```
http://localhost:8888/template-membership/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/images/girl-bg.jpg
```

This means that somewhere in your code you are either hard-coding the string `wp-content/themes/` into the path to the image, or you are using some function to add this in.

So you simply need to locate what is generating this unneeded string in your code. Perhaps you could post the relevant code and I can break it down further for you.